# Trying to run a .NET app but keep getting this error

Tags: .net-core

I'm trying to run a small app using .NET Core 2.x SDK on a Macbook. So far I've run dotnet restore to restore NuGet packages and then dotnet build to build the webapp. However when I input dotnet run I get the following error in my terminal.

Failed to load /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.0.9/libhostpolicy.dylib, error: dlopen(/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.0.9/libhostpolicy.dylib, 0x0001): tried: '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.0.9/libhostpolicy.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/local/lib/libhostpolicy.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libhostpolicy.dylib' (no such file)
An error occurred while loading required library libhostpolicy.dylib from [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.0.9]

The version I downloaded was .NET SDK Arm64 as .NET SDK x64 didn't seem to work for the dotnet commands I mentioned previously. I'm not familiar with .NET at all so any help for this error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's to do with a Mac dependency and I don't think the 2.x SDK is supported anymore, at least not long term support. You should be using the latest 3.1 - remove all the old 2.x SDK components.

Comment: how did you solve it? I get some problem